# Python 3.X NameError

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and this code was written in PyCharm. I changed probability to p to prevent conflicts of it not being declared link to tutorial article here [the site I got it from](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-code-a-fair-coin-flip-in-python-d54312f33da9)

```
import numpy as np




def coinFlip(p):
    #perform the binomial distribution (returns 1 or 0)
    result = np.random.binomial (1 , p)
    #return flip to be added to numpy array
    return result



'''Main Area'''
#probability of heads vs. tails. this can be changed
p = .5
#num of flips required. this can be changed
n = 10

#initiate array
FullResults = np.arrange(n)

#perform the desired number of flips required probability set above
for i in range(0, n):
    fullResults[i] = coinFlip(p)
    i+=1

#print results
print("probability is set to ", p)
print("Tails = 0, Heads = 1: ", fullResults)
#Total up heads and tails for easy user experience
print("head count: ", np.count_nonzero(fullResults == 1))
print("Tail count: ", np.count_nonzero(fullResults == 0))
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Are you getting an error? Is the code misbehaving?

Comment: Also, you need to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
def coinFlip(p):
    #perform the binomial distribution (returns 1 or 0)
    result = np.random.binomial (1 , p)
    #return flip to be added to numpy array
    return result
'''Main Area'''
#probability of heads vs. tails. this can be changed
p = .5
#num of flips required. this can be changed
n = 10

#initiate array
#################FullResults = np.arrange(n)
FullResults = np.arange(n)
#perform the desired number of flips required probability set above
fullResults = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(0, n):
    fullResults[i] = coinFlip(p)
    i+=1
#print results
print("probability is set to ", p)
print("Tails = 0, Heads = 1: ", fullResults)
#Total up heads and tails for easy user experience
print("head count: ", np.count_nonzero(fullResults == 1))
print("Tail count: ", np.count_nonzero(fullResults == 0))
```

I had to make two minor modifications -

1. np.arange(n) instead of np.arrange(n)
2. I initialized the array fullResults with zeros

Here is the output -

```
  probability is set to  0.5
    Tails = 0, Heads = 1:  [0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
    head count:  4
    Tail count:  6
```

Comment: so i tried what you did, but i get this error instead? im new to python and am using this as a learning oppourtunity heres the error. 
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeroes'

Comment: @BranCereal It is should be 'zeros' not 'zeroes'